# How to change the primary display of dual screen Fedora 16?

Tags: fedora, display-settings

I have a dual display Fedora 16. How can I change the primary screen (the one with the panel)?

Comment: What video driver are you using? (Nouveau, nvidia proprietary, radeon, fglrx, …)

Comment: I still haven´t install driver for video. As I recall, my video card was some Radeon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use a proprietary display driver with its own display controls, you can open `gnome-control-center` (e.g. after hitting ALT+F2) and select "Displays". Here, you can simply drag the black bar from the top (it represents the panel) and drag it to the symbol of the desired screen:
[image: Gnome's display settings]

All this assumes Gnome 3.2.

Comment: OMG, I´ve missed the big black bar on top of the displays. 10x.